# Could someone please identify this fluorescent plant?

Tags: identification

I live in Tucson, Arizona, and was out looking at scorpions with a medium-wavelength ultraviolet light. I happened to shine it on this plant. Wow! Can someone please identify the plant for me.

The plant lives on the north side of the house, right at the bottom of that wall. There are probably six to eight small clumps.

The pix show the plant in the daytime and under the UV light at night.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

[image: The plant in daytime.]

[image: The plant under UV illumination.]

Comment: Cool , I would set up UV exterior lights.

Comment: Flowers would help.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a "Hound's Ear" *Bupleurum rotundifolium* or a rocket seedling to me. And fyi, any plant with hairy surface can show red fluorescence under UV light due to Raman effect scattering the blue lightrays of shorter wavelength and leaving hints of red as red wavelength is least scattered.

Comment: Are you able to substantiate this in any way ?

Comment: @RohitGupta, I grew a few rockets (arugula) awhile back this year, the emerging seedlings were quite similar to the ones being shown here, also, judging by the daylight luminescence, the location can be judged of being somewhere cool (or the image had been captured at dawn), which justifies that they might be rocket. As for Bupleurum, Google Lens is showing the reverse search to be Bupleurum and owing to its invasive nature it does possess a  probability of it. As for UV lighting experimentation: https://www.instructables.com/Glowing-Foods-Cooking-colorfully-in-ultraviolet-l/

Comment: @RohitGupta Also, lately I've been lately seeing a lots of rocket in this SE, it is a rocket season.